# Is it possible to capture a specific node/div in the HTML content loaded in a webview?

Tags: android, kotlin, mobile, webview, android-webview

I have managed to make a full screenshot of a web page loaded in a webview. But I would like to be able to target a specific div and just capture its content.

For instance opening this url in a webview, would it be possible to capture the div surrounded in red?
[Webview content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dcjhP.png)

I'm using the getBitmapFromView() function to capture de webview and this is the code sample (the image is then saved in directory and encoded in Base64 but that is irrelevant to the subject at hand)

```
screenButton.setOnClickListener {
    val baos = ByteArrayOutputStream()
    val randomID = Random().nextInt()
    val bitmap = getBitmapFromView(scrollView, scrollView.getChildAt(0).getHeight(), scrollView.getChildAt(0).getWidth())
    val externalStoragePublicDirectory =
        Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)
    val imageFile = File(externalStoragePublicDirectory, "Screenshot$randomID.png")
    FileOutputStream(imageFile).use {
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 70, it)
    }
   
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos)
    val imageBytes: ByteArray = baos.toByteArray()
    val imageString: String = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(
            imageBytes
        )
    } else {
        TODO("VERSION.SDK_INT < O")
    }
    println("Base64 Encoding : $imageString")
}
```

And this is the result [Webview screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMyme.jpg)

Comment: You might want to look into taking a screenshot in JavaScript, and see if you can pass that data back to the `WebView`'s `JavascriptInterface`. Android doesn't have any knowledge of what's going on inside the `WebView`, doesn't know anything about the DOM, so I don't think you can screenshot specific elements natively - it would have to be done inside the `WebView`. All Android can do is look at what's displayed in the `View` itself, which is why you're getting the entire page - you might be able to crop it though, maybe get some coordinates passed to the JS Interface (not an expert though!)

Comment: what you want to do can be done outside of android, that is, you must use some web automation tool (eg appium)

Comment: Having checked the webview API I did figure that it was not possible to with simply that @cactustictacs . I will check the JavascriptInterface though, I didn't try that yet, thanks !

Comment: Never tried automation tools, if you have a link to a specific tool ou tutorial I would appreciate it thanks ! @ElDavid